# How does Boost know to find an absolute path from the relative one?

Tags: c++, boost

I have a problem where my files have a relative path and I need to convert them to the absolute.

I use the following boost file system methods to solve it:

```
    fs::path full_path( boost::filesystem::initial_path<boost::filesystem::path>() );
    full_path = fs::system_complete( boost::filesystem::path( path ) );
    full_path.normalize();
```

And it works!

The question is how?How boost knows to find the absolute path from the relative if the former even isn't located at the same directory as the executable?

The relative path comes from a node of an XML file and it is relative to it.Not to the executable.

Comment: if the path is relative to the working directory, since the working directory is known, the implementation is fairly trivial.

Comment: It would, in fact, be more difficult to portably find out the path relative to the executable.

Comment: The path is not relative to the working directory.It comes from an xml file which resides somewhere on the file system.The relative file path is relative to that XML

Comment: we have 3 entities here: 1) the working dir, 2) the relative path; 3) the path to which 2) is relative. In order to create the absolute path of 2) you need 2) and 3). There is something missing in your problem. You absolutely need 3) to compute the absolute path. Maybe is used somehow not obvious or maybe 1) is set to 3)

Comment: The code you have there resolves the same way the OS would for a call to `open`, which is from the working directory (or the working directory on the drive in question, on Windows, if the path is something like `D:foo.txt`). Boost.Filesystem has another function called `absolute` that does the same from arbitrary directories, but if the above code works, your working directory is the one to which the paths are relative.

Comment: How about downloading boost source code and looking at how it works?